# R Tools for Visual Studio not installing properly in VS2017

Tags: r, visual-studio-2017, rtvs

I tried installing the "R tools for Visual studio" in visual studio 2017, as explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/rtvs/installation#installation-in-visual-studio-2017 , but after installation nothing shows up in VS2017. The description on that web page doesn't properly describe the installation UI: step 3 mentions making sure that "R language support", "Runtime support for R development", and  "Microsoft R client" are selected, but only the latter is available as an option - the first two are nowhere to be found. I am trying to get it installed on VS 2017 professional, on windows 7.

I also tried the installation for VS 2015, and that seems to work fine.

Does anyone know if I am doing something wrong, if the installer is bugged, or if something else is going on?

Comment: Exact same issue.

Comment: I have got this to work fine on my windows 10 surface book, but my windows 7 work pc is giving me exactly the same error. Maybe an OS problem?

Comment: I just found an install log file that indeed indicates installation requires windows 10. It would be nice if Microsoft could explain why that requirement exists, or if it just is there out of habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been [logged as a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/RTVS/issues/3561) on the RTVS Github repo.

> Customers have reported that R in the VS 2017 Data Science Workload is blocked from installing on Windows 7. We have verified this issue and have a fix prepared for the next update of Visual Studio 2017.
>
> We are currently working with the Visual Studio team to get this fix deployed as quickly as possible.